# Android Image Cropper Library Image is not getting Match Parent in width and Height

Tags: android, image, android-studio, cropper

In my new create Project i add image cropper library and it is not being match parent, i have tried all, below i am sharing my code and sdk versions.

```
 implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
```

here is my main class where I am using this library as

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private  val cropActivityResultContract  =  object  :
ActivityResultContract<Any? , Uri?>(){
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Any?): Intent {
        return  CropImage.activity()
            .getIntent(this@MainActivity)
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
       return CropImage.getActivityResult(intent)?. uri
    }

}
private lateinit var cropActivityResultLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<Any?>
private lateinit var chooseImage : Button
private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    chooseImage = findViewById(R.id.imgSelectImage)
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image)

    cropActivityResultLauncher  = registerForActivityResult(cropActivityResultContract) {

        it?.let {
            imageView.setImageURI(it)
        }
    }

    chooseImage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        cropActivityResultLauncher.launch(null)
    })
}}
```

below is my XML File here I am getting cropped image its working fine after crop :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/imgSelectImage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:text="Choose Image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I am Attaching my screenshot of device please check this as well

[image: Screen shot of Image]

Image is not fill in view background,please check image below. please suggest me thank you in advance, i would appreciate every suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Package Name of Project and Issue resolved